# CKEditorError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: reactjs, redux, ckeditor

CKEditorError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-Cannot convert undefined or null to object.

```
    const [mainDesc, setMainDesc] = useState('');
    const handleMainDesc = (e, editor) => {
        const text = editor.getData()
        setMainDesc(text)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setMainDesc(data?.desc)
    }, [data]);

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const formData = {};
        formData['id'] = data?.id
        formData['description'] = mainDesc
        dispatch(updateServiceMainDesc(formData))
        setTimeout(() => {
            callback(true)
            handleClose()
        }, 1000)
    };

    <CKEditor editor={ClassicEditor} data={mainDesc} onChange={handleMainDesc} />
```

Comment: where is the `data` property?

Comment: its coming through props and its just a string or null const { data, callback } = props